# Can we show that the result of an integral of a function of polynomial order is always one degree higher?

Tags: integration, asymptotics

Is it true that if $$ \int f(x)\,\mathrm dx = g(x) $$

for $f\in\mathcal O(x^n)$, then $g$ must be in $\mathcal O(x^{n+1})$ where $\mathcal O$ denotes big-O notation and $ n \ge 1 $ is an integer?

If it is true, how can we prove it?

If it is false, can we have a counterexample as the answer?

Comment: The question is not well defined because on the RHS you have a natural number, but on the LHS you will always get $ax+c$ where $a,c \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Eminem Why is the RHS a natural number? I have specified the RHS as a function, say, $ g(x) $, where $ g(x) = O(x^{n + 1}) $. Also, how is the LHS always $ ax + c $. On the LHS I have a function $ f(x) $, where $ f(x) = O(x^n) $? (Edit: I see Prasun Biswas has edited my question to make this clearer. Thank you, Prasun!)

Comment: @LoneLearner: I have edited your question to make it explicit because it seems the previous user mistook the (abuse of?) notation to mean something else. Feel free to modify/change it back if it there is any problem.

Comment: The statement is false. Let $f(x)=x^{-1}$, then $g(x)=\ln(x)+C\notin O\left(1\right)$. Also if $f(x)=x^{-n}$ for some positive $n$ then $g(x)=x^{-n+1}+C$ which is $O(1)$, not $O(-n+1)$ as claimed.

Comment: @Kyky Thank you for the counterexample. I have added a constraint that $ n
\ge 1 $ is an integer. Sorry for changing the scope of the question.

Comment: Informally, I think this holds: even the stronger assertion that if $f\in\Theta(x^n)$, then its indefinite integral must be in $\Theta(x^{n+1})$ holds, I think. Let me see if I can come up with a rigorous proof. Good question. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

(I've decided to delete my old answer since I had made a step that was false. I decided that the proof was unsalvageable and wrote this proof instead)

For some $n>-1$ and $f(x)\in O\left(x^n\right)$, suppose that $$g(x)=\int f(x)dx\notin O\left(x^{n+1}\right)$$

Now this implies that there does not exist real $k$ such that, provided $x>x_0$ for some real $x_0$, $$g(x)\leq kx^{n+1}$$

Or alternatively, for every real $k$ and $x>x_0$ we have $$g(x)\leq kx^{n+1}$$

Taking the derivative:

$$\frac d{dx}g(x)>\frac d{dx}kx^{n+1},x>x_0$$

$$f(x)>k(n+1)x^n,x>x_0$$

However, since $f(x)\in O\left(x^n\right)$, this implies that there exists $M$ and real $x_1$ such that $$f(x)\leq Mx^n,x>x_1$$

Let $k=\frac M{n+1}$. The equation we obtained by taking the derivative becomes $$f(x)>Mx^n,x>x_0$$

But when $x>x_0$ and $x>x_1$ then we have

$$Mx^n\geq f(x)>Mx^n$$

Clearly a contradiction.

$\therefore$ $g(x)\in O\left(x^{n+1}\right)$